# Javascript beginner if.else to switch conversion

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm a complete beginner to JavaScript and have been looking into this for quite some time now, I feel I've tried a lot of different ways of writing this code and it just doesn't seem to work as intended, nothing happens at all.

I want to convert this if statement:

```
if (browserName == "MSIE") {
} else if (browserName == "IE11+") { 
} else if (browserName == "Chrome") { 
} else if (browserName == "Firefox") {
} else if (browserName == "Safari") {
} else alert("your browser is not compatible, please use one of these web browsers: Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer or Apple Safari.")
```

into a switch statement, this is what I currently have:

```
switch (browserName) {
    case '1': == "MSIE"();
        break; 
    case '2': == "Safari"();
        break;
    case '3': == "Chrome"();
        break;
    case '4': == "IE11+"();
        break;
    case '5': == "Firefox"();
        break;
    default:
        alert("test1");
}
```

I just want it to skip to the else alert if it does not detect the browser's name.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should detect the feature, not the browser. Or Firefox 0.9 (approx.ly 2004) would be fine?

Comment: What do you mean with ` == "MSIE"();`?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan An excellent point, but not relevant from the point of view of how to use a `switch` statement.

Comment: @JLRishe that's why I wrote a comment and not an answer. and detecting a feature would be probably easier than any switch statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to convert it to a switch statement is as follows:

```
switch (browserName) {
    case "MSIE":
        break; 
    case "Safari":
        break;
    case "Chrome":
        break;
    case "IE11+":
        break;
    case "Firefox":
        break;
    default:
        alert("Your browser is not compatible, please use one of these web browsers: Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer or Apple Safari.");
}
```

and you could also do it this way:

```
switch (browserName) {
    case "MSIE":
    case "Safari":
    case "Chrome":
    case "IE11+":
    case "Firefox":
    default:
        alert("Your browser is not compatible, please use one of these web browsers: Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer or Apple Safari.");
}
```

but it would probably be better to do something like this:

```
function checkBrowser(browserName) {
    var compatibleBrowsers = ['MSIE', 'Safari', 'Chrome', 'IE11+', 'Firefox'];
    if (compatibleBrowsers.indexOf(browserName) !== -1) { return; }

    alert("Your browser is not compatible, please use one of these web browsers: Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer or Apple Safari.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. it worked perfectly. I understand what I was doing wrong now. :) great help

Answer (score 2):

The values after `case` should be the values that you want to match:

```
switch (browserName) {
    case "MSIE":
        // do something
        break; 
    case "Safari":
        // do something
        break;
    case "Chrome":
        // do something
        break;
    case "IE11+":
        // do something
        break;
    case "Firefox":
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        alert("test1");
        break;
}
```

If all you care about is the case when the value doesn't match any of the known values, you can stack the `case`s together:

```
switch (browserName) {
    case "MSIE":
    case "Safari":
    case "Chrome":
    case "IE11+":
    case "Firefox":
        break;
    default:
        alert("test1");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
switch (browserName) {
    case "MSIE": //Do MSIE work here
        break; 
    case "Safari": //Do Safari work here
        break;
    case "Chrome": //Do Chrome work here
        break;
    case "IR11+": //Do IE11+ work here
        break;
    case "Firefox": //Do Firefox work here
        break;
    default:
        alert("Browser Not Recognized!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a switch statement, you can't do:

```
case '1': == "MSIE"();
```

Instead do:

```
  case 'MSIE':
     //do code
     break;
```

Hope it helps.